# When thinning on the right how is it correct that the number of formulae on the right can be increased from zero to one?

Tags: logic

I understood there being no formulae to the right of the turnstile as meaning that the formulae on the left was inconsistent. However, my textbook writes that there is a special case of thinning on the right, namely: if Γ ⊨  then Γ ⊨ ψ. For me, this appears to conflict with the definition of the turnstile, what makes this example correct?

Comment: Why does it conflict with the definition? Certainly if Gamma is inconsistent then it entails psi for every psi - vacuously.

Comment: This is just the [law of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).